# spawning a robot from urdf with origin parameters through ros in gazebo 1.8

Tags: gazebo-1.8

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I tried to upgrade from Gazebo 1.5 from source to Gazebo 1.8  from .deb package. And everything seemed to work fine also the ROS integration worked fine by using the `simulator_gazebo` package.

The only thing which didn't seem to work was spawning the robot model with an initial pose:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file robot.urdf -urdf -x 1 -y 1 -z 1 -R 3.1415 -P 0 -Y 0 -model robot
```

The robot got spawned in the world, but the initial position was ignored.
I think it has to do with the urdf parser (`parser_urdf.cc`) which doesn't come with the `ParseRobotOrigin` function anymore.
In `gazebo_ros_api_plugin` in the `updateURDFModelPose` function the `origin_key` gets both attributes `xyz` and `rpy` set correctly. so I assume that in gazebo this is not read correctly or it should be set differently now.

Does anyone have a solution for that, or should I file a bug?

Cheers Fadri

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2979/spawning-a-robot-from-urdf-with-origin-parameters-through-ros-in-gazebo-1.8/) by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 349 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khausman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/364/khausman/) on 2013-05-24**:
Hi everyone,

I noticed an issue that might be related with the one above. After setting the pose of a model (a box for example) in the .world file it is being spawned at the correct position but gazebo gui always says that it is at 0 0 0 0 0 0 pose. I tested with Gazebo 1.8, Gazebo 1.5 doesn't have this issue.

Should I also report it as a bug?

Thanks for help,
Karol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok this is fixed with this merge https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/559/merge-fixes-from-catkin_groovy-back-into/diff

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) with karma: 349 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0